# org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Checked exception is invalid for this method

Tags: mockito, junit5

I am trying to test service layer using junit5 with spring boot 2.6.2, and I want to test throwing exception if the account not found,

I wrote the below test method

```
@Test
    void getUserAccountWithUserAccountNotFoundExceptionTest() {
        /**
         * TODO tried to to test it but getting this error
         * Checked exception is invalid for this method
         */
        when(this.systemUserRepository.findByEmailAddress(emailAddress)).thenThrow(UserAccountNotFoundException.class);
        Assertions.assertThrows(UserAccountNotFoundException.class, ()->{
            this.manageUserAccountService.getUserAccount(emailAddress);
        });
    }
```

snippet of the service Implementation
@Service
public class ManageUserAccountServiceImpl {
.............
@Override
public UserAccountDto getUserAccount(String emailAddress) throws UserAccountNotFoundException {
......
.......
}
..........
}

User Account not found exception class

```
public class UserAccountNotFoundException extends UserAccountException {

    public UserAccountNotFoundException() {
        super();
    }

    public UserAccountNotFoundException(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        super(errorCode, errorMessage);

    }

    public UserAccountNotFoundException(Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace,
            int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        super(cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace, errorCode, errorMessage);
    }

    public UserAccountNotFoundException(Throwable cause, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        super(cause, errorCode, errorMessage);
    }

}
```

User account exception class

```
public class UserAccountException extends Exception {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -591169136507677996L;
    protected ErrorInfoDto errorInfoDto;

    public UserAccountException() {
        super();
    }

    public UserAccountException(Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression,
            boolean writableStackTrace,int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorInfoDto = formErrorInfoDto(errorCode, errorMessage);
    }

    public UserAccountException(int errorCode,String errorMessage) {
        this.errorInfoDto = formErrorInfoDto(errorCode, errorMessage);
    }

    public UserAccountException(Throwable cause,int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorInfoDto = formErrorInfoDto(errorCode, errorMessage);
    }
    
    private ErrorInfoDto formErrorInfoDto(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        ErrorInfoDto errorInfoDto = null;
        errorInfoDto = new ErrorInfoDto();
        errorInfoDto.setErrorCode(errorCode);
        errorInfoDto.setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
        return errorInfoDto;
        
    }
    
    public ErrorInfoDto getErrorInfoDto() {
        return errorInfoDto;
    }
}
```

Repository interface

```
public interface SystemUserRepository extends JpaRepository<SystemUser, Long> {
    long countByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);

    long countByMobileNo(String mobileNo);

    Optional<SystemUser> findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
    
}
```

Comment: You need to show us `systemUserRepository` and not  `ManageUserAccountServiceImpl `.  It could be that doing that answers your question )

Comment: I have edited the post by showing the SystemUserRepository interface, check the post please

Comment: As I said, you answered the question by yourself by posting the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Mockito` exception says it alone - the line `when(this.systemUserRepository.findByEmailAddress(emailAddress)).thenThrow(UserAccountNotFoundException.class);` instructs Mockito to throw exception when `systemUserRepository.findByEmailAddress(...)` is called.

However, the posted code for `SystemUserRepository` does declare any checked exception on the method: `Optional<SystemUser> findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);`

Note also that `SystemUserRepository` handles the case of user not found by giving an `Optional.empty()` and not by throwing an exception.